# iPhone 5 app displaying correctly but not sensing touches in "extra" space

Tags: ios, uiview, ios6, nib, iphone-5

I "converted" my app to be iPhone 5 compatible by adding the `Default-568h@2x.png` startup image and all appeared to be working fine. The app is a simple Navigation Controller app which starts with a `UITableView`.

By "appears to be working", I mean that the initial `UITableView` displays fine on the iPhone 5, occupying the entire screen properly. However, the view doesn't respond to touch events in the bottom 176 pixels, exactly the "new" area for the iPhone 5.

In the annotated screenshot below, the red area doesn't respond to touch events. The problem occurs on all the views of my app. At first I thought it was a simulator bug, but I've tested on an iPhone 5 and the problem is the same. Also, this particular app is the only one that has this issue.

I suspect it has something to do with the fact that the app was first created a long time ago (around the time of iOS 3.x), and that there's something in those old NIB files which is messing things up.

I've tried changing the view sizes and autoresizing masks but nothing makes any difference, and it's driving me crazy!

[image: The area in red doesn't respond to touch events]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add this line in your `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method, it should solve your problem:

```
window.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

Alternatively, you can enable the *Full Screen at Launch* checkbox of your window under the Attributes Inspector of the xib file.

Comment: Thanks! You've seen this one before then?

Comment: Yes, this happens for all apps which were created with the old Xcode template containing the `MainWindow.xib` file.