# Using EGOPhotoViewController with iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios, iphone-5, pushviewcontroller

Using this on iPhone 5:

```
EGOPhotoViewController *photoController = [[EGOPhotoViewController alloc] initWithImageURLs:imageURLs];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:photoController animated:YES];
```

When I get back to the caller I can see the bottom bar... How should I solve this?

That doesn't happen on 3.5 inch screen.

**UPDATE:**
Same problem happens on EGOPhotoViewer_Demo
This is how the screen looks on the first usage:
[image: Original Screen]

When getting into "Photos" and go back to that main screen it change to:
[image: After releasing photos screen]

You can see something hides the bottom of the screen. On my app I have buttons there so it's problematic.
Hope this update makes my problem more clear.

Comment: If you are using storyboard, disable autolayout and the bar goes back to where it needs to be.

Comment: Not using Autolayout.

Comment: I've updated the question, Hope this clears those issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When compiling with Xcode 5 the problem is solved (test device was iOS 7).

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure but this might be a duplicate of [iPhone 5 app displaying correctly but not sensing touches in “extra” space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13021298/21698)

Also, do you have the same problem on iOS 6? From the screenshots, it seems you are using iOS 7, which could be the source of your problem.

Comment: Your link doesn't help. I don't know if it works on iOS 6 because my iPhone 5 test device is already been upgraded. Anyway, compiling with Xcode 5 seems to solve the issue but I would really like to use the old Xcode because I have to submit it working...

Comment: What's the problem with iOS7 - is there a link to that? I am having the same issue but only when running in iOS 7. App was compiled in 6.1.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

The problem is the following statement in viewWillAppear:

```
        [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

Move this statement and the accompanying "if" test to viewDidAppear and the problem goes away.

To be honest I am not sure why this ever worked - but it makes sense that showing the toolbar when our photo view is *not yet up* would show the toolbar in the parent view, not the photo view. Moving it to viewDidAppear does the right thing.